# How to execute two loop simultaneously in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two lists:

```
 host_list = ["10.3.11.250", "10.3.24.45", "10.5.3.5","10.3.4.5"]
 ip_value = ["34.45.34.5", "10.3.11.250","10.3.4.5"]
```

I want to check whether the data of host_list is present in ip_value or not if it is then append the ip_value to another list. I am doing in this way check the following code:

```
for host,ip in zip(host_list ,ip_value):
    if host_list == ip_value
        list_ip = list_ip.append(ip)
```

But it does nothing.Why? and what should list_ip returns
it will returns: {"10.3.11.250", "10.3.4.5"}

Comment: But more importantly, are the items in host_list some kind of IP objects? Normal strings do not have a `.ipv4` or `.ipv6` attribute.

Comment: OP posted sets (enclosed in `{}`). Someone edited it to lists (enclosed in `[]`).

Comment: /me steps slowly away from what looks like an edit war in the making.. stets or lists, make up your mind! :-P @eumiro: The OP starts with "I have two lists:".

Comment: @MartijnPieters done that was my mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are **sets**, not lists. You can calculate a difference of them:

```
list_ip = host_list - ip_value
```

returns

```
{'10.5.3.5', '10.3.24.45'}
```

**Edited**: ok, now they are two lists. Change the code to:

```
list_ip = list(set(host_list) - set(ip_value))
```

returns

```
['10.5.3.5', '10.3.24.45']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `set`s

```
another_list = list(set(host_list) - set(ip_value))
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, why does the code you give do nothing:

```
for host,ip in zip(host_list ,ip_value): 
    if host_list == ip_value 
        list_ip = list_ip.append(ip)
```

You are comparing host_list to ip_value, and not comparing host to ip.  host_list != ip_value, thus the next statement is never executed.